# Open a libreoffice mail merged textdocument directly with swriter

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, mailmerge, office-automation

I need help with opening the result of my mail merge operations directly in an new writer document.

```
    Object mailMergeService = mcf.createInstanceWithContext(mailMergePackage, context);
    XPropertySet mmProperties = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, mailMergeService);
    mmProperties.setPropertyValue("DocumentURL", templatePath);
    mmProperties.setPropertyValue("DataSourceName", dbName);
    mmProperties.setPropertyValue("CommandType", mmCommandType);
    mmProperties.setPropertyValue("Command", mmCommand);
    mmProperties.setPropertyValue("OutputType", mmOutputType);
    // mmProperties.setPropertyValue("OutputURL", templateDirectory);
    // mmProperties.setPropertyValue("FileNamePrefix", mmFileNamePrefix);
    // mmProperties.setPropertyValue("SaveAsSingleFile", mmSaveAsSingleFile);
```

The mmOutputType is set as MailMergeType.SHELL
The LibreOffice API documentation says

***"The output is a document shell.
The successful mail marge returns a XTextDocument based component."***

So I've tried something like this

```
    XJob job = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XJob.class, mailMergeService);
    Object mergedTextObject = job.execute(new NamedValue[0]);

    String url = "private:factory/swriter";
    loader.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]);

    XTextDocument mergedText = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, mergedTextObject);
    XTextCursor cursor = mergedText.getText().createTextCursor();
    cursor.setString(mergedText.getText().getString());
```

I guess I have to pass the XTextDocument component to the url-argument of the loadComponentFromURL method but I didnt find the right way to do that.

When I change the OutputType to MailMergeType.FILE the result is generated in a given directory and I can open the file and see that the mail merge succeeded. But this is not what my application should do.

Does someone know how I can open the result of the mail merge directly in an new writer document without saving the result to the hard drive?

Sincerly arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey guys I've found a simple way to open the result of my mail merge process directly.

The relevant snippets are these

```
  XJob job = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XJob.class, mailMergeService);
  Object mergedTextObject = job.execute(new NamedValue[0]);
  XTextDocument mergedText = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, mergedTextObject);
  mergedText.getCurrentController().getFrame().getContainerWindow().setVisible(true);
```

The last line of code made the window appear with the filled mail merge result.

I also **don't need** this line anymore

```
loader.loadComponentFromURL("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]);
```

The document opens as a new instance of a swriter document. If you want to save the result as a file you can do this

```
  mergedText.getCurrentController().getFrame().getContainerWindow().setVisible(true);
  XStorable storeMM = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, mergedText);
  XModel modelMM = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, mergedText);
  storeMM.storeAsURL(outputDirectory + outputFilename, modelMM.getArgs());
```

Sincerly 
Arthur

Comment: Good, I thought the code using `loadComponentFromURL` was heading in the wrong direction.  Glad to see you figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What version of LO are you using?  The [SHELL](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/namespacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1MailMergeType.html#a34ba3778d34ae4ee10257edf9fa9c3b0) constant has only been around since LO 4.4, and it is not supported by Apache OpenOffice yet, so it could be that it isn't fully implemented.  However [this code](http://lcov.libreoffice.org/sw/qa/extras/mailmerge/mailmerge.cxx.gcov.html) seems to show a working test.

If it is returning an [XTextDocument](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1XTextDocument.html#details), then normally I would assume the component is already open.  However it sounds like you are not seeing a Writer window appear.  Did you start LO in headless mode?  If not, then maybe the process needs a few seconds before it can display.

```java
Object mergedTextObject = job.execute(new NamedValue[0]);
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Anyway to me it looks like your code has a mistake in it.  These two lines would simply insert the text onto itself:

```java
XTextCursor cursor = mergedText.getText().createTextCursor();
cursor.setString(mergedText.getText().getString());
```

Probably you intended to write something like this instead:

```java
XTextDocument mergedText = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, mergedTextObject);

String url = "private:factory/swriter";
XComponent xComponent = loader.loadComponentFromURL(url, "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]);
XTextDocument xTextDocument = (XTextDocument)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, xComponent);
XText xText = (XText)xTextDocument.getText();
XTextRange xTextRange = xText.getEnd();
xTextRange.setString(mergedText.getText().getString());
```

One more thought: `getString()` might just return an empty string if the entire document is in a table.  If that is the case then you could use the view cursor or enumerate text content.

EDIT:

To preserve formatting including tables, you can do something like this (adapted from https://blog.oio.de/2010/10/27/copy-and-paste-without-clipboard-using-openoffice-org-api/):

```java
// Select all.
XController xMergedTextController = mergedText.getCurrentController();
XTextViewCursorSupplier supTextViewCursor =
            (XTextViewCursorSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XTextViewCursorSupplier.class, xMergedTextController);
XTextViewCursor oVC = supTextViewCursor.getViewCursor();
oVC.gotoStart(False)  // This would not work if your document began with a table.
oVC.gotoEnd(True)
// Copy and paste.
XTransferableSupplier xTransferableSupplier = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTransferableSupplier.class, xMergedTextController);
XTransferable transferable = xTransferableSupplier.getTransferable();
XController xController = xComponent.getCurrentController();
XTransferableSupplier xTransferableSupplier_newDoc = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTransferableSupplier.class, xController);
xTransferableSupplier_newDoc.insertTransferable(transferable);
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your reply I tried your solution and it's now half working for me. The second thing to create a new XTextDocument and pass the value from the mergedText into it. But now I have the problem that the format of my template is not used. Do you know how I can keep the formatting of my template file? By the way I'm using LO 5.0.3.2 (x64)

Comment: For additional information: My template has a bold centered heading font size 16, Some key-value pairs left oriented with standard font, a horizontal line and an 2-cols and 3 rows table again with key-value pairs.

Comment: Hey Jim thanks for your help but I've found a simplier way to do this. Check my answer if you are interested in.